# mysql full-text boolean search operators have no effect

Tags: mysql

Why is it that with **multiple match against** statements the + operators won't do there job anymore?
The results i get now contain *OR ziekenhuis, OR bed, OR hospital*,...

I want to get (**ziekenhuis AND bed**) **OR** (**hospial AND bed**)...

Thank you!

```
SELECT * FROM archief WHERE MATCH(description, keywords) 
AGAINST('+ziekenhuis +bed' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
OR MATCH(description, keywords) AGAINST('+ziekenhuis +bed' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
OR MATCH(description, keywords) AGAINST('+hospital +bed' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
OR MATCH(description, keywords) AGAINST('+lit +d\'hôpital' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

AND showa = '1' 
AND rel_date <= '20110630' 
ORDER BY datetaken desc LIMIT 50
```

Answer (score 0):

The 3 letter words in your query are probably being ignored if you are using the default setting for ft_min_word_len of 4.

You can check the setting like this:

```
show variables like 'ft_min_word_len';
```

If you want 3 letter words to be indexed, you need to change the setting in your config file and restart MySQL. For example, open up your /etc/my.cnf file and add/update this line in the [mysqld] section:

```
ft_min_word_len = 3
```

Then restart your MySQL server for the change to take effect. You should also consider setting that value even lower if you want shorted words to be indexed. And you should review the MySQL default [stopwords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) list to see if you want any of those words indexed. You can ignore the stopwords list and index all words my adding this to the [mysqld] section of your my.cnf file:

```
ft_stopword_file = ''
```

Also, you don't need to use multiple MATCH statements, you can do it all in the boolean logic of the string you are matching against.

Try this once you've updated your server:

```
SELECT * 
FROM archief 
WHERE 
MATCH(description, keywords) 
  AGAINST('(+ziekenhuis +bed) (+hospital +bed) (+lit +d\'hôpital)' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
AND showa = '1' 
AND rel_date <= '20110630' 
ORDER BY datetaken desc 
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: this sounds very logic, but there is no difference between the outcome, both with or without parentheses gives records that contain at least one of the two words

Comment: It's probably the problem of the 3 letter words not being indexed if you are using the default ft_min_word_len of 4. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: In that case check your stopwords list and/or try the updated query in my answer.